# Need help to check error log and decide to continue or exit

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I am writing a batch file.  The purpose is I run a commond, and catch the log file in "log.txt"  if this log.txt file contains "return code: 8" or "return code: 12" or "return code: 16"  I must stop execution for remaining.

Sample batch file is as below (SAP Transport)

```
For /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (trlist.txt) do (
  tp import %%a SYSTEMID client=%%b u01 pf=c:\trans\sap\bin\dbc.pfl 1>>c:\log.txt 2>&1
  findstr /C:"return code: 8" c:\log.txt
  if errorlevel 0 goto END
  findstr /C:"return code: 12" c:\log.txt
  if errorlevel 0 goto END
  findstr /C:"return code: 16" c:\log.txt
  if errorlevel 0 goto END
)

Echo "Processed successfully ...:">c:\result.txt
Echo "Check the c:\log.txt file " >>c:\result.txt
Exit

:END
Echo "Error occured... " > c:\result.txt
Echo "Check the c:\log.txt file." >>c:\result.txt
Exit.
```

after each execution of TP, check the log.txt file.  If this contains any of the above mentioned return code, should stop further execution.

Script is getting exited though "return code: 4" and "return code: 0" which should not exit.

I am running the above bat file on Windows 2008 server.

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` will return true of it is 0 or higher.  Read this page to understand errorlevel checking.  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From R H L's link:

> `IF ERRORLEVEL` returns TRUE if the return code was equal to *or higher than* the specified errorlevel

This means that when you check for `ERRORLEVEL 0`, it will ***always*** return true.  You need to instead check for `ERRORLEVEL 1`, which will return true if  your string was not found, or check for `NOT ERRORLEVEL 1`, which will return true if your string was found.

Like this:

```
...
findstr /C:"return code: 8" c:\log.txt
  if not errorlevel 1 goto END
...
```

Comment: Dear All  Thank you for your support.  Yes I misunderstood errorlevel representation.